# Can't trigger 'dragenter'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I can't get dragenter to work. This is (an excerpt of) my code to demonstrate: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/burktelefon/30rqdf6k/).

```
$(".droppable").droppable({
  drop: function (event, ui) { // try replacing 'drop' with 'dragenter'
    var o = ko.dataFor(this);
    alert(o.low + "-" + o.high);
  }
});
```

Anyone has a clue to what I'm missing?

Comment: Droppable has no event "dragenter", see http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/ Maybe you need "over".

Comment: Aha! I thought you could use all standard events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Comment: So I learned something today :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the "over" event. Droppable has no dragenter.

```
$(".droppable").droppable({
    over: function (event, ui) {
        var o = ko.dataFor(this);
        alert(o.low + "-" + o.high);
    }
});
```

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/30rqdf6k/3/